# Match em string não funciona com 1 caracter

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Tenho o seguinte obstáculo:

```
var myString = "c/q/1";
var match = myString.match(/c\/q\/([a-zA-Z0-9-].+)/);
```

Porém `match` retorna como `null`, já no seguinte exemplo:

```
var myString = "c/q/stringdegrandevalor";
var match = myString.match(/c\/q\/([a-zA-Z0-9-].+)/);
```

`match` é retornada com o valor procurado, o que me leva a crer que seja o tamanho da string na expressão numérica 1, que esteja gerando este problema, como eu poderia resolvê-lo?

Comment: Tente: `/c\/q\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/` ... http://jsbin.com/rafemikuba/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retire o ponto `.`.

Com o ponto você está dizendo que após `c/q/` deve ter o `[a-zA-Z0-9-]` e algum outro caractere (qualquer um), logo se você colocar apenas 1 caractere após o `c/q/`, o padrão não casa, porque seriam necessários pelo menos 2 caracteres (sendo o 1º no padrão `[a-zA-Z0-9-]`) após a última barra `/`.

[Segundo esta documentação](https://regexone.com/lesson/wildcards_dot), o ponto é um *metacaractere* que significa "qualquer caractere".

Com o ponto:

```
                        .
                        ↓
 c/q/1{cadê o caractere aqui exigido pelo ponto?}
     ↑
[a-zA-Z0-9-]
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var myString = "c/q/1";
var match = myString.match(/c\/q\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/);
console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 3):

Vamos quebrar a parte final da expressão (`[a-zA-Z0-9-].+`) para entender melhor:

- `[a-zA-Z0-9-]`: significa "uma letra, número ou traço"
- `.`: significa "qualquer caractere"
- `+`: significa "uma ou mais ocorrências" da expressão anterior

  - ou seja, `.+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere"

Portanto, a expressão `[a-zA-Z0-9-].+` significa "o primeiro caractere pode ser letra, número ou traço, e depois tem uma ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere".

Ou seja, esta expressão está pegando no mínimo dois caracteres.

Se o que você quer é "uma ou mais ocorrências de letra, número ou traço", você deve remover o `.`, e portanto a expressão deve ser `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+`.